# How to add Bing Maps layer in Angular using ngx-leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I want to add a Bing Maps layer to my leaflet map. I am using the ngx-leaflet types in Angular 9. I found this Bing Maps plugin (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-bing-layer) for leaflet. Not sure how to make it work with ngx-leaflet.